# notify is not called only wait is getting called

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a class called Customer there i have two methods waitThread and
notifyThread . Both the methods will hold a same lock obj. waitThread in the while loop of synchronized block will call wait method ,the lock of thread1 is released and other thread say thread2  need to go for notifyThread method and set the flag value to true. But the output iam getting is

Both the thread1 and thread2 are entering in waitThread method. None of them are entering the notifyThread method . Can anyone please suggest what is going on here ,why it is not entering the notifyThread method. If it needs to enter notifyThread what can be done?

```
public class Customer implements Runnable
{

public boolean flag=false;

public Object obj=new Object();

     public void run()
      {
        waitThread();
        notifyThread();
       }



public void waitThread()
{
  synchronized(obj)
  {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThred().getName()+"in the waitThread");

        while(!flag)
       {
           System.out.println(Thread.currentThred().getName()+"in the waitThread calling wait");

           try
          {
             obj.wait();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
         {
         }
       }


   }
 }

public void notifyThread()
{
  synchronized(obj)
  {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThred().getName()+"in the notifyThread");

        flag=true;
 System.out.println(Thread.currentThred().getName()+" notify the previous thread");

    obj.notify();


}


   }

}


}
```

Creating two threads

```
public class Test
{

public static void main(String args[])
{

Customer cus=new Customer();

Thread t1=new Thread(cus);
Thread t2=new Thread(cus);
t1.start();
t2.start();

}

}
```

Comment: I am not sure how you compiled your code, spelling mistake in - `Thread.currentThred()` .

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `waitThread()` method first, so both the threads go into the WAIT state and remain there. No one is invoking the `notify()` method for the threads to come out of the WAIT state.

```
public void run()
{
    waitThread();// HERE, wait is getting called first.
    notifyThread(); // control doesn't come here at all.
}
```

Comment: if the obj.wait() and obj.notify() methods are commented then control is going to notifymethod . i think some concept lies with calling of .wait()